# SQL para saber qual o último registro editado

Tags: sql, query

Tenho a seguinte SQL:

```
$dcadastroultimo = date("d.m.y");
$sqlidcidade = "select id, titulo, tipo from imoveis where cod = '$cliente' AND
ueditado <= '$dcadastroultimo' ORDER BY id ASC";
```

Preciso que liste os últimos registros editados, porém vários são editados com a data do mesmo dia, como faço para listar na ordem de edição mesmo sendo no mesmo dia?

**Exempo:**

Tenho os registros:

**ID - Atualização**

```
101 - 15.03.2016
159 - 15.03.2016
243 - 15.03.2016
```

Só que o último editado foi o **ID 159** e ele é o terceiro da lista, preciso que ele fique em primeiro.

Aguardo ajuda!

Comment: Como é que você está registrando a ordem exata da edição?

Comment: Você está registrando somente a data, ou data e hora?

Comment: `ORDER BY ueditado DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você registra a data edição na coluna ueditado. Então se você ordenar pela coluna ueditado em order decrescente.

```
$sqlidcidade = "select id, titulo, tipo from imoveis where cod = '$cliente' ORDER BY ueditado DESC";
```

Caso você queira somente o último, você pode utilizar o statement LIMIT.

```
$sqlidcidade = "select id, titulo, tipo from imoveis where cod = '$cliente' ORDER BY ueditado DESC LIMIT 1";
```

`LIMIT 1` faz com que apenas o primeiro registro encontrado seja retornado.

**Detalhe importante:** se você está armazenando no banco de dados `ueditado` como date e não como timestamp, não importa a <s>magia</s> query que você utilize, não será possível buscar com precisão qual foi o último registro editado.